# Incorporating a time series into a mixed model in R

Tags: time-series, mixed-models

I have a time series of deployment sondes, which measure different parameters in a 2-minute interval, such as Chlorophyll RFU. I have 2 treatment groups, namely ponds without fish and ponds with fish. I am interested in whether Chlorophyll RFU differs in ponds without fish vs. ponds with fish. I am not interested in the temporal pattern of Chlorophyll RFU in this case, I just want to account for the obvious strong dependency of Chlorophyll RFU on time (time is in fractions of days since start of measurements), together with the fact measurements temporally closer together are stronger correlated. How can I incorporate time correctly into my mixed model in this case? So far my model looks like this:

```
library(nlme)
vf1 <- varIdent(form= ~ 1|Fish)
m.vf <- lme(Chlorophyll_RFU ~ Fish + Time_seq,
            random = ~1|Sonde,
            weights = vf1,
            na.action=na.exclude,
            data = dat2)
```

My model so far just incorporates time as a common effect. The parameter of Time_seq so far is not interpretable, due to the periodic changes of Chlorophyll RFU over time (no linear relationship). I additionally added a variance function and a random intercept, but this is not of relevance for my question.

I am honestly not quite sure what to do, because my research question is about inference on Chlorophyll RFU depending on Fish, and no inference about the temporal pattern. Hence I am not aiming to make a classical ARIMA model or anything, I just want to account for time correctly, so that my model doesn't overestimate the impact on Fish on Chlorophyll RFU.